# Is there any way to semi-automatically commit?

Tags: windows, git, dreamweaver, commit

Please bear with me here, because I'm a beginner when it comes to version control systems. I've decided to start with the very simple GitHub app. What I want to do is (because I work in Dreamweaver) when I save a file a window to pop-up and ask me if I want to commit, is something like this achievable and if so... then how?

Comment: FYI: I made the "git" tag first, and removed it from the title. If you look in your title bar, the first tag is mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there's a solution that uses a directory watcher to watch for changes and then prompt?

In my opinion, this isn't really a good solution though - you don't just want to use Git as a "backup" solution, you want each commit to be a mini-milestone that represents some logical group of changes.  I can't think of a single instance where the first time I saved a change to a file it was commit-worthy.  If you were to commit with every save, how would you ever test those changes?

Comment: I have to agree with Jonathan.  As you are developing and saving small changes you do not want to commit something that is not working.  In a multi-developer environment other people could end up checking out your unfinished code.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll just stick with manually commiting changes or as you said milestones. Do you think the GitHub application is good enough for a beginner or should I consider more advanced alternatives like SourceTree?

Comment: I think using the GitHub client is a fine way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but the [GitWeaver](https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver) extension may be what you are looking for.